# Why is rsync getting "permission denied" errors on Mac OS X when ACLs are set for the correct user?

Tags: rsync, access-control-list, osx-snow-leopard

I'm transitioning away from an old tool that initiates an `rsync` (copying from a local path to a remote path w/SSH hostkeys) via a web form (completely behind a firewall w/multiple authentication layers, not that that's an excuse) hosted on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard Server. To work around the fact that `rsync` is run by `_www`, but the files are owned by `someuser` (plus the SSH hostkeys are for `someuser`), the original author made a copy of the `rsync` binary w/permissions of 4755 & `someuser` as the owner (so, anyone who runs that copy of `rsync` has it run as the `someuser` user). A dirty hack, for sure, but it works (and it was written before Mac OS X even had support for ACLs, so it's at least *slightly* understandable, though it's still atrocious from a security standpoint).

As my first step in moving away from this solution, I've changed the permissions of those files from 777 (owned by `someuser`) to 755 (still owned by `someuser`), then set ACLs for `_www` to have full access to those files, as follows:

```
chmod -R +a "_www allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /path/to/directory
```

Unfortunately, while still using the same `rsync` binary with the set-user-ID-on-execution bit set for `someuser`, `rsync` now throws the following error:

```
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/path/to/directory/subdir/." failed: Permission denied (13)
done

sent 332 bytes  received 20 bytes  704.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-30/rsync/main.c(717)
```

If I check the permissions for that directory, they seem correct:

```
$ ls -ael /path/to/directory/
total 0
drwxr-x---+  3 someuser  admin  102 Jun 23 19:00 .
 0: user:_www allow list,add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxr-xr-x   8 someuser  admin  272 Jun 23 18:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x+ 17 someuser  admin  578 Jun 23 17:15 subdir
 0: user:_www allow list,add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

The same is true of a file in the directory:

```
$ ls -ael /path/to/directory/subdir/file.txt 
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 someuser  admin  107 Jun 23 17:15 subdir/file.txt
 0: user:_www allow read,write,delete,append
```

What would cause this permissions error since the files are still owned by the user which the `rsync` binary runs, plus the `_www` user should have full ACLs for the directory & files?

**Update:** It seems like it's an ACL issue as running `sudo -u _www ls -ael /path/to/directory/` results in "permission denied" errors as well:

```
ls: .: Permission denied
ls: ..: Permission denied
ls: subdir: Permission denied`
```

So, what's wrong with the ACLs I've set?

Comment: Maybe your `chmod` command should have been `chmod -R +ai ...`, i.e. `+ai` instead of `+a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Server Admin.app, I enabled the "Show system accounts in the users & groups browser" preference, then went to File Sharing and browsed to `/path/to/directory/` (w/"Volumes" & "Browse" selected in the toolbar) I added a "Custom" ACL (no "Administration", but all "Read", "Write", and "Applies to") for the '_www' user and propagated the permissions.

This resulted in the following when running `ls` as the '_www' user:

```
$ sudo -u _www ls -ale /path/to/directory
total 0
drwxr-x---+  3 someuser  admin  102 Jun 23 19:00 .
 0: user:_www allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxr-xr-x   8 someuser  admin  272 Jun 23 18:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x+ 17 someuser  admin  578 Jun 23 17:15 subdir
 0: user:_www inherited allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

So, that resolved the issue. By looking at the ACLs that were set, it looks like it was probably the missing 'search' access which was causing the failures (maybe some of the others, although those appear to only be related to extended attributes).

Answer (score 0):

If you transfer files to remote storage (like FreeNAS, etc) - don't forget to set correct rules.
Not only set **owner**, but include this ownerto **read-write list** also.

[image: freeNAS example]

I'm hooked on this.